# Playing random pairs of words in Sound Arrays

Tags: java, audio

My goal is to play doublets (pairs) of the phrase "This is a test", which is a WAV audio file. So far I succeeded in generating a random sequence of the phrase, such as "Test is this a", but I need to make it so that it only speaks in pairs, so "This is"... "Is a"... with a 100 m.second pause between each word and a 400 m.second pause between each pair. This is what I have thus far...

```
public void playDoublets(int numDoublets) throws InterruptedException {
    ArrayList<Sound> list = new ArrayList();
    for (int i =0; i < numWords; i++){
        list.add(new Sound(myWordArray[i]));
    }
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    for (int i = 0; i < numWords; i++){
        list.get(i).blockingPlay();
        Thread.sleep(400);
    }
}
```

numDoublets is how many pairs the program plays, but I do not know where I would implement it in the code above. All this code does so far is just print out all 4 words, but not in pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly represent a pause in your list of sounds you want to play. Use an interface to generically handle both normal sounds and pauses.

```
import java.util.*;

public class DoubletPlayer {
    private static final int PAUSE_BETWEEN_WORDS = 100;
    private static final int PAUSE_BETWEEN_DOUBLETS = 400;

    public static void main(String... args) {
        DoubletPlayer player = new DoubletPlayer();
        player.playDoublets(2);
    }

    interface Playable {
        void play();
    }

    class Sound implements Playable {
        private String word;

        public Sound(String word) {
            this.word = word;
        }

        @Override
        public void play() {
            System.out.println("sound played: " + word);
        }
    }

    class Pause implements Playable {
        private int millis;

        public Pause(int millis) {
            this.millis = millis;
        }

        @Override
        public void play() {
            System.out.println("pause of " + millis + "ms");
        }
    }

    private List<Sound> sounds = new ArrayList<>();
    private int currentSound = 0;

    public DoubletPlayer() {
        sounds.add(new Sound("This"));
        sounds.add(new Sound("is"));
        sounds.add(new Sound("a"));
        sounds.add(new Sound("test"));

        Collections.shuffle(sounds);
    }

    public void playDoublets(int numDoublets) {
        List<Playable> doublets = generateDoublets(numDoublets);
        playAll(doublets);
        reset();
    }

    private List<Playable> generateDoublets(int numDoublets) {
        List<Playable> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numDoublets; i++) {
            addDoubletTo(result);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void addDoubletTo(List<Playable> result) {
        result.add(getNextSound());
        result.add(new Pause(PAUSE_BETWEEN_WORDS));
        result.add(getNextSound());
        result.add(new Pause(PAUSE_BETWEEN_DOUBLETS));
    }

    private Playable getNextSound() {
        return sounds.get(currentSound++);
    }

    private void playAll(List<Playable> result) {
        for (Playable playable : result) {
            playable.play();
        }
    }

    private void reset() {
        currentSound = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome solution, but during this assignment, I am not allowed to create interfaces, I have to use the classes/methods that they provided me. If you need more information, please let me know,